# Plotting row based data

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have some data that looks something like this:

```
df =

id      period    15-nov    16-nov    17-nov    18-nov
------------------------------------------------------
vodka   night     1         2         3         1
vodka   day       0         1         2         0
vodka   evening   1         2         2         0
rum     night     1         2         3         3
rum     day       1         2         2         0
rum     evening   1         3         2         1
```

What I would like to do is to plot the values of the header dates, but grouped by id and period. So essentially this would become 6 line plots, with the x-axis given as the dates.

However, maybe I'm just tired, but this data set is weirdly put together imo, so my usual `groupby` stuff doesn't work because only some of the headers are the x-axis values. I was thinking about transforming the date columns into one single column, and then adding the date headers as another column giving me 4 total columns - but more rows, and then use the `groupby` function. But I can't think of any clever way to do this, accept maybe doing it kind of manually.

So is that the way for me to go, or am I missing an easy transformation trick ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could unpivot your dataframe using [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) and then use seaborn to plot the lines:

```
import seaborn as sns

df_melted = df.melt(value_vars=['15-nov', '16-nov', '17-nov', '18-nov'], 
                    id_vars=['id', 'period'], 
                    var_name='date'
                   )

sns.lineplot(data=df_melted.sort_values('date'), 
             x='date', y='value', 
             hue=df_melted['id'] + '_' + df_melted['period']
            )
```

Output:

[image]